# Frustrated With Xamarin android support Library appcompat v7

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

I have Visual Studio 2015,Xamarin,JDK,SDKs installed but still getting error when ever I'm trying to install and use android support library appcompat v7.
I've tried many methods but remains same.

Comment: What is the error? Also the v7 AppCompact library is installed by default in the project if you created a new Xamarin Android or Xamarin Forms solution. Is it not installed in your project already? If not, have you tried creating a new Xamarin Android or Xamarin Forms solution and seeing if it gets installed correctly in the new solution?

Comment: If you can show us an error or some other info about your issue that will be great.

Comment: here is the error list
http://www.mediafire.com/download/oz1dq0bpq2bza21/E.txt

Comment: If you guys want anything else just let me know

Answer (score 0):

This error often happens when there is a corrupted ZIP containing the Android libraries. I have seen this occur under a few different circumstances, such as a network issue while these libraries are downloading, or a cancelled build when the download is occurring.

The best way to resolve this, is to completely remove the previously attempted libraries, and attempt your build again (which will download fresh copies of the library). Please follow the steps below:

1. Open Windows Explorer
2. Navigate to C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\
3. Delete everything in C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips\
4. Attempt build again

This should fix it :)

Thanks!